# unable to hide/visible div panel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 3 individual div's(in aspx page and making all 3 div's visible="false").

Based on condition I have to show 1 div at a time and remaning two div's to hide

I am doing in javascript as making 1 div as `style.visibility = "block";` and other 2 div's to `Style.Add("display", "none");`

while running it is throwing error msg as:

> unable to get the value of the property 'style': object is null or
>   undefined

Below is the code, in aspx:

```
 <div runat="server" id="div1" visible="false">
 ..
 </div>

 <div runat="server" id="div2" visible="false">
 ..
 </div>
 <div runat="server" id="div3" visible="false">
 ..
 </div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    var val =  "xx1" (or "xx2" or"xx3")
  switch (val) {
     case "xx1":
     document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1').Style.Add("display", "none");
       // document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div2').style.visibility = "block";
    //document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div2').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div3').Style.Add("display", "none");
    case "xx2":
     document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1').Style.Add("display", "block");
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div2').style.visibility = "none";
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div3').Style.Add("display", "none");
    case "xx3":
     document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1').Style.Add("display", "none");
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div2').style.visibility = "none";
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div3').Style.Add("display", "block");

});
```

Comment: Looks like you are using JQuery, why not write the rest in JQuery?

Comment: If i am making visible="true"(in aspx page making all 3 div's) while loading the page it showing all the 3 div's and then 2 div's are hiding and they are taking space for each even though they are hidden.

Comment: Why are you adding the styles? just go either `.style.display = 'none';` or `.style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Also, you have `.Style` and `.style` ... pretty sure it should be `.style`

Comment: In your example `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1` doesn't exist in your html? Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for visibility is:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility="hidden";
```

But you can use jQuery :

```
    $("#YourSelector").hide();

    $("#YourSelector").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `visible="false"`. When you do that client-side control is not rendered at all - it simple doesn't exist.

Instead if you want to hide it, but still make it available to client code do

```
<div runat="server" id="div1" style="display:none">
 ..
</div>
```

or

```
<div runat="server" id="div1" style="visibility:hidden">
 ..
</div>
```

depending on how you want to hide it.

After that your client-side code will be able to locate and manipulate it.

Matter of fact - if you don't need to access these DIVs on the server, you can remove `runat="server"` attribute altogether. Bonus: Unaltered DIV id (you can use `'div1'` instead of `'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_div1'`)

Comment: thxs for ur reply. modified  the code to style="visibility:hidden">. But it is taking space for the hidden div's. how to aviod this?

Comment: This is why I offered alternative "*depending on how you want to hide it.*". Instead of `style="visibility:hidden"` use `style="display:none"`

Comment: after adding this style="display:none" It is giving error for as "unable to get the value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined"

Comment: It should make no difference which style is applied; the DIV should still be availabe as long as you dont reenable visible="false"